# Proper Error Handling in java

Tags: java, exception

I need to know how to handle the exceptions in a situation like below. Please assist me,

```
public interface DCommand {

    public Object execute(Class_A car);
}

public class Class_B {

    public void getMessage() throws Exception {       
            throw new Exception("Test error");
    }
}

public class Class_A {

    Class_B cb = null;

    public Class_B getClass_b() {
        cb = new Class_B();
        return cb;
    }

    public Object testAction(DCommand command) {
        Object returnObject = null;
        try {
            return (Boolean) command.execute(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR IN CLASS B" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return returnObject;
    }
}


====================== simiulating ============================

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class_A c = new Class_A();

        boolean a = (Boolean) c.testAction(new DCommand() {

            @Override
            public Object execute(Class_A car) {
                try {
                    car.getClass_b().getMessage();
                    return true;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error in the simulator.");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


    }
}
```

When I run the above code I need to catch the exception thrown by the Class_B in the Class_A where prints the "ERROR IN CLASS A".

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are throwing a type of Exception in your Class B's getMessage method. Instead you should define your own exception by extending `java.lang.Exception`.

```
public class ClassBException extends Exception {
   public ClassBException(String msg) {
      super(msg);
   }
}
```

And then use ClassBException to be thrown in Class B's getMessage method like this

```
public class Class_B {
    public void getMessage() throws ClassBException {       
            throw new Exception("Test error");
    }
}
```

Now you need to a have separate catch block for ClassBException at any place you are calling  Class B's getMessage method.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Methode to class A:

```
public void runGetMessage()
{
   try{
     cb.getMessage();
   }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Error in CLASS A.");
   }
}
```

And change the Execute methode to:

```
public Object execute(Class_A car) {
    try {
          car.getClass_b();
          car.runGetMessage();
          return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
          System.out.println("Error in the simulator.");
    }
    return false;

   }
```